# Is there a way to take energy from matter beyond 0°K and if yes, what would it do?

Tags: energy, temperature

From my simple understanding, as you cool down a piece of matter, you take energy from it (neglecting the energy needed to cool it down).

Is there a limit to this? Is that limit absolute zero (0°K) ? 
What would happen if you could somehow take away more energy? 
Does this equate the conversion to another element?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature

Comment: @pentane Negative-temperature objects are typically very hot. In that context, you have to use a formal definition of temperature which doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the kinetic energy of the particles in the ensemble (and thus doesn't have much to do with the usual notions of "cool" and "hot").

Answer (score 3):

Energy can come in different forms. Temperature is a measure of *kinetic energy*, or energy of movement; when we measure temperature, what we're really measuring is how much the atoms are jiggling around inside. So if the object is at absolute zero, we cannot remove any more *kinetic energy*. The object, and all of its atoms, are absolutely still.

I'm speaking roughly, of course; quantum mechanics is relevant at absolute zero, and many familiar notions break down. One example of a weird thing that happens as matter approaches absolute zero is that the atoms can become delocalized and form a coherent "matter wave," a result of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. If kinetic energy is zero, then momentum is zero (kinetic energy $=p^2/2m$), so uncertainty in position is infinite.

So you cannot remove any more kinetic energy, but other forms of energy are possible (for instance, you could let it annihilate with antimatter, so it releases radiation).